# How to display the keys of a python dictionary as HTML table headers and values of each key as a row under that table header?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm currently working in a django project in which I do some data analysis using pandas library and want to display the data (which is converted into a dictionary) as a HTML table.

dictionary that I want to display:

```
my_dict = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'product_name': [product1, product2, product3, product4, product5],
    'value': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000],
    'available_qty': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
}
```

I want to display the above dictionary like this table in django template.

| id | product_name | value | available_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | product2 | 400 | 2 |
| 3 | product3 | 600 | 3 |
| 4 | product4 | 800 | 2 |
| 5 | product5 | 1000 | 4 |

I have tried the below code.

```
<table>
    <thead><h2><b>my dictionary</b></h2></thead>
        {% for key, values in my_dict.items %}
            <th><b>{{ key }}</b></th>
            {% for value in values %}   
                <tr>
                    {{value}}
                </tr>   
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I get the results as,

[image: HTML table result]

(There is some space between each row displayed in the table)

Comment: better first convert to `list of rows` (and you can use `zip()` for this) and later send it to template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better first convert to list of rows (using `zip()`) and send this to template

```
my_dict = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'product_name': ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5'],
    'value': [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000],
    'available_qty': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
}

all_headers = list(my_dict.keys())

all_rows = list(zip(*my_dict.values()))

print(all_headers)
for row in all_rows:
    print(row)
```

Result:

```
['id', 'product_name', 'value', 'available_qty']
(1, 'product1', 200, 1)
(2, 'product2', 400, 2)
(3, 'product3', 600, 3)
(4, 'product4', 800, 2)
(5, 'product5', 1000, 4)
```

And then template could be (but I didn't test it)

```
<h2>my dictionary</h2>

<table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
      {% for header in all_headers %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
      <tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      {% for row in all_rows %}
      <tr>
         {% for value in row %}   
            <td>{{ value }}</td>   
         {% endfor %}
      <tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `pandas` then you could use `df.to_html()` to generate table

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

html_table = df.to_html(index=False)

print(html_table)
```

and it gives HTML similar to code from my previous template

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>product_name</th>
      <th>value</th>
      <th>available_qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>product1</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>product2</td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>product3</td>
      <td>600</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>product4</td>
      <td>800</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>product5</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And you can send `html_table` to template and  you have to display it with option `safe` (so it will not convert `<` `>` to `&lg;`, `&gt;`)

```
{{ html_table | safe }}
```

Comment: I addes simpler version with `panda` `to_html()`

Comment: The to_html() method looks good and does everything I need. Thanks for this answer @furas it saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

## In your template

- **Load filters**

```
{% load filter %}
{% block body %}
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for key in my_dict %}
                    <th scope="col">{{ key }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in my_dict|RANGE %}
                <tr>
                    {% for key, value in my_dict.items %}
                        {% if forloop.counter0 < my_dict|length %}
                            <td>{{ value|items:i }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

## In project/app/ create a folder called templatetags

- In your templatetags folder there will be

  - **init**.py
  - filters.py
- put the following code in filters.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def RANGE(dictionary):
    length = 0
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if length < len(value):
            length = len(value)
    return list(range(length))


@register.filter
def items(List, index):
    return List[index]
```